# How long can one starve before refeeding syndrome becomes an issue?

Tags: survival, food

[Refeeding syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refeeding_syndrome) is a potentially fatal condition caused by eating too much or too fast after a period of starvation.

My question is, how long of a period are we talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked Wikipedia article's [first reference (pdf)](https://www.nice.org.uk/guidance/cg32/resources/nutrition-support-for-adults-oral-nutrition-support-enteral-tube-feeding-and-parenteral-nutrition-pdf-975383198917) recommends to start precautions at the 5 day mark when tube-feeding. These precautions are to feed only 50% of calorie needs for the first two days and continue as normal if no problems arise. Further, a patient at high-risk of refeeding syndrome would need to be cared for by an expert. They should start feeding further below the metabolic rate, ramp up during the next 4-7 days.

The article gives these criteria for a high risk for refeeding syndrome:

At least one of

- BMI less than 16 kg/m<sup>2</sup>
- Unintentional weight loss greater than 15% during the last 3-6 months
- Little to no nutritional intake for more than 10 days

**OR**
At least two of

- BMI less than 18.5 kg/m<sup>2</sup>
- Unintentional weight loss greater than 10%
- Little to no nutritional intake for more than 5 days
- A history of alcohol abuse or drugs including insulin, chemotherapy, antacids or diuretics

So, start taking precautions if starvation has lasted 4-5 days and seek professional help if you match the above criteria.